# Sum of difference of elements around a point in matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, octave, convolution

I'm trying to rewrite and speedup my code.
Basicaly I have a matrix, and I have to for every element in the matrix calculate a sum of differences of neighbouring elements around that element. For example for this kind of 3x3 matrix i should get:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9

(1-2)+(2-3)+(3-6)+(6-9)+(9-8)+(8-7)+(7-4)+(4-1)
```

I know that this type of sum I can easily perform by using convolution with kernel

```
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

But I have to somehow perfom the substruction first. I've written a code in octave that performs this operation as is, but it's very inefficient so I'm trying to move to c++ with openCV and speed up the process.

My question is, is there a way to perform this operation using some sort of matrix operation istead of a brute force summation?

Code in octave that currently work

```
function deltaPhi = phaseDifference(phi1, phi2)
  deltaPhi = phi1 - phi2;
  if(deltaPhi > pi)
    deltaPhi = deltaPhi - 2*pi;
  endif

  if(deltaPhi < -pi)
    deltaPhi = deltaPhi + 2*pi;
  endif;

end

function [phase] = checkPhase(M)

phase = zeros(size(M)-2);


  for i = 2:size(M,1)-1
    for j = 2:size(M,2)-1      
      phase(i-1,j-1) = phaseDifference(M(i-1,j-1),M(i,j-1)) + phaseDifference(M(i,j-1),M(i+1,j-1)) + phaseDifference(M(i+1,j-1),M(i+1,j)) + phaseDifference(M(i+1,j),M(i+1,j+1)) + phaseDifference(M(i+1,j+1),M(i,j+1)) + phaseDifference(M(i,j+1), M(i-1,j+1)) + phaseDifference(M(i-1,j+1), M(i-1,j)) + phaseDifference(M(i-1,j), M(i-1,j-1));
    endfor
 endfor

end
```

Comment: 1) "_I'm trying to rewrite and speedup my code._" As far as we are concerned - you don't have any code (since you don't show any). 2) If you have functional code, and are only looking to improve performance, have a look at [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @tobi303 Sorry, I added a question.

Comment: But I'm still looking for similar way of substructing a neighbour or at least shifting elements position around a chosen point

Comment: If you group the positive and negative items in your formula `(1-2)+(2-3)+(3-6)+(6-9)+(9-8)+(8-7)+(7-4)+(4-1)  --> (1+2+3+6+9+8+7+4) - (2+3+6+9+8+7+4+1) --> 0`  you will see that all of them cancel out, so your result will always be 0. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki You should write that up as an answer. It's certainly the most efficient solution.

Comment: There are functions to do this in the image package and you never, never should do this using nested for loops

Comment: @Andy I know, that's why I'm looking for help in turninig this into more efficient code.

Comment: Glock, if you know that there are functions for this in the octave-forge image package, why are you then writing your own code?

Comment: I meant, I know I souldn't use nested for loops, but I dont know which image package functions to use.

Comment: Glock, if you don't use @ to adress the person it won't get a notification. It's pure luck that I've seen this. You are looking for the octave-forge "image" package https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

If you group the positive and negative items in your formula you will see they all cancel each other, so the result is always 0.

```
(1-2)+(2-3)+(3-6)+(6-9)+(9-8)+(8-7)+(7-4)+(4-1) 

     (1+2+3+6+9+8+7+4) - (2+3+6+9+8+7+4+1) 

                       0
```

Instead, if you want differences in neighbor pixels, you might want to use some existing kernels (for edge detection, blurring, sharpening...)

Take a look at [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) to see the most used Kernels and what they do

Comment: I'm working on phase of wave function, so the example I gave maybe misleading, because the value of pixel/matrix element can be only between -π to π

Comment: Doesn't matter. Your elements cancel all out, so it means that no matter their value (even if infinite) the result will be 0

Comment: Sorry, i didn't metion that if the difference is either bigger or smaller than π or -π than i have to substruct or add 2π. I added appropriate code in octave.